# OSX Services - character substitution + for _

Tags: macos, automator, services

I've created a service to use primarily in a browser for searching IMDB, so instead of copying and pasting the film's name I just select the text and run the service I created which will automatically search IMDB for the selected text. This works perfect.

[image]

I was hoping to do the same for Wikipedia and so i've been trying to modify the same service but have come across a problem. The search query places a "+" between each word.

This doesn't work for Wikipedia. They place underscores between their words.

[image]

I wondered how I can substitute the + for _?
This is what I currently have

```
open "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/$(ruby -rcgi -e 'print CGI.escape $<.read.chomp')"
```

Kinds regards and Merry Christmas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WikiPedia places underscores for its entry URLs, but you can `search` any string (actually with spaces) with this URL scheme:

`http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=[query]`

Replace `[query]` with you search query.

Try this for example: [Search for "stack overflow"](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=stack%20overflow)

It redirects to correct page. If it can't determine which entry to show, it shows a list of possible entries you can select from: [Search for "stack overfloww"](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=stack%20overfloww).

**TL;DR**

Moreover, if you separate words in query with `+`, it works just fine. So all you need to do is replace

```
                               ↓↓↓↓↓↓
open "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/$(ruby -rcgi -e 'print CGI.escape $<.read.chomp')"
```

with this:

```
                               ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
open "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=$(ruby -rcgi -e 'print CGI.escape $<.read.chomp')"
```

Comment: @Frasier013 Since we're on the subject, [this](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/keysearch/) is a great Safari extension for searching in different sites from the address bar. Since you're using El Capitan, follow the first post [here](http://www.igetter.net/forums/showthread.php3?threadid=1598) to install it in case you ran into problems.

Comment: Thanks buddy, i'll check out that extension. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
open "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/$(ruby -rcgi -e 'print CGI.escape $<.read.chomp' | sed 's/+/_/g')"
```

`sed 's/+/_/g'` replaces all instances of + with _